Solana blockchain: query historical token holdings for an address
Is it possible, through the Solana CLI or API, to figure out the SPL token holdings of a given address at a given point in time (e.g. a block or actual date)? I couldn't find any API or CLI commands that allowed specifying a block, as they all seem to operate on the most recent block.
For comparison, this is how it is done for Ethereum-based blockchains: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40266/get-balance-history-of-address
Thank you.

Using the normal RPC, you can't do this unfortunately. Some other services that do historical snapshots might exist, but you'll need to research these

Thanks. I found https://github.com/c29r3/solana-snapshot-finder but it seems it only queries the latest snapshot available from each RPC node, which is not old enough. I'm looking for a snapshot from 1-2 months ago. I haven't been able to find any source to download older snapshots.
